# Visual Studio Code Red Unerlines

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I started programming python in vsc.
My problem is, that everything is underlined red but if I compile the code he is working. So the code doesn't seems to be wrong.
[image]

Has anybody an idea what could cause this problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: what do the tooltips of the squiggles tell you, or look in the PROBLEMS Panel, what is your LanguageId (lower right)

Comment: it wants spaces on either side of operators(`=,>`) and also expects only 1 blank line between `oldFriends = {}` and your function definition ... these are style errors not logic or syntax errors

Comment: switch of the linter (PyLint) or fix the problems

Comment: *"Has anybody an idea what could cause this problem and how I can solve it?"* Please, for your own sake, get out of the habit of ignoring what the computer says to you. You might be used to ignoring unhelpful error messages from Windows or Microsoft Office or so on, but when you are programming, you must read the errors and warnings, and try to understand them - they are not meaningless. If your IDE shows a red squiggly line under some of your code, then it will also tell you why that red squiggly line is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, these are not syntax errors, but style errors. Python code usually follows the PEP8 standard found at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Your VSCode is likely using a python linter (style checker) that is trying to get you to follow this style. While it would be possibly to unconfigure this linter, it would be more preferable to adapt to following this style guide as it will make your code more consistent and more readable, especially if you begin to share this code with other python developers.

Another benefit of learning to follow this style for yourself is that it will help you to be better at reading python code written by others.

Following this style guide, your code may look something like this:

```
old_friends = {}

def older_friend(friends, age):
    for key, value in friends.items():
        if value > age:
            old_friends[key] = value
    print(old_friends)
```